# shell command in dmake adds '/S'

Tags: windows, bash, makefile, mingw, porting

I'm working on compiling Xindy with a MinGW system. `dmake` always dies with an error, and I've narrowed it down to a couple of lines in the Makefile. Try running dmake on this:

```
SHELL = /bin/sh
some-target:
    target=`echo info-recursive | sed s/-recursive//`;
```

If you are using the regular Windows CMD instead of a MinGW shell, you have to change the location for the SHELL variable to point to something like "C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/sh.exe". Anyway, the above fails with:

```
CreateProcess failed (2).
dmake: Error executing 'bin/sh /S /c "target=`echo info-recursive | sed s/-recursive//`;"': No such file or directory
dmake: Error code -1, while making 'some-target'
```

Sed and sh are installed and they work fine. When I try and run the given command as output by the error message by itself, I get this:

```
$ /bin/sh /S /c "target=`echo info-recursive | sed s/-recursive//`;"
/bin/sh: /S: No such file or directory
```

So it seems that dmake (or something) is adding the '/S /c', to the shell argument, and bash thinks it's a file name and then fails when it can't find it.

Does anyone have experience with this or know how I can fix this?

Comment: Normally, `bash` or `sh` options must begin with '-', so `/bin/sh -S -c "..."` would be expected. I don't know MinGW at all, so I couldn't say who is at fault.

Comment: The '/' instead of a '-' doesn't surprise me too much, since lots of Windows programs do that (though I disapprove)

Comment: Yeah, I just don't have any hands-on experience to say "dmake is calling /bin/sh wrong", although that would be my first guess.

Comment: yes, agree with all above that /c (especially) should be -c, but I'm  also looking at the lines above that. "executing 'path/to/sh ...'"? Surely that's your shorthand? Can you edit to include the exact error message? Also, it's not clear (to me) if you're using `SHELL = C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/sh.exe` or `SHELL = /bin/sh`. Finally, is cygwin your fall-back command-line tool or otherwise involved? This sounds like something cygwin would do. (To make it clear, I have much more experience with Mingw than cygwin). Good luck.

Comment: Edited to fix. I was using the MinGW path, which is more Unixy. Cygwin is not involved anywhere.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Brief examination of the *dmake* source code suggests that the problem is that `$(SHELL)` is being set too late and is still empty at startup time ([macros.mk](http://code.google.com/a/apache-extras.org/p/dmake/source/browse/trunk/startup/winnt/macros.mk), line 37):

```
11  .IF $(SHELL) == $(NULL)
...
15     SHELL *:= $(COMSPEC)
...
...
35  .IF $(SHELL) == $(COMSPEC)
36  .IF $(COMSPEC:lf) == cmd.exe
37     SHELLFLAGS       *:= $(SWITCHAR)S $(SWITCHAR)c
```

You may be able to work around this by adding `SHELL="C:/MinGW/msys/1.0/sh.exe"` to your dmake command line invocation.

(I haven't used dmake in many years and so may be mistaken here, but I will be impressed if you can get what looks like an autoconfiscated makefile to work with dmake, which IIRC has a somewhat different flavour.  It might be easier to find a GNU *make* or similar.)

Comment: Yes, this seems to have solved the immediate problem, after which many others popped up. I had assumed that MinGW came with dmake, not make (I feel silly), so I'm retrying with MinGW's make and it sees to be doing better.